# Facebook iOS SDK and Open Graph ID as an identifier

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am developing an app that allows users to share selected data with their friends and conveniently using the Facebook iOS SDK allows me to easily let users pick the friends that they would like to connect with.

I am currently watching WWDC 2015 video 703 about Privacy and Your App.  At 24:30 ish, it is clearly stated that if you are using "private APIs to build a persistent identifier, you are in violation of the app store terms and there will be consequences."

The Facebook ID is persistent in that it can be recovered even after the app is removed from the device if the user was to re-install and login again with Facebook.

Am I understanding this correctly that I am only allowed to use Apple's identifiers and use of Facebook's identifiers is a violation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure in this context they mean if you're using "private APIs" from iOS, for tracking purposes. Not having an ID for users that have logged into your app just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think of it that way.  Now that I re-read it as 'private APIs' from iOS it is consistent with what they have said in the past.  Thanks for the comment, that may have been the answer I was looking for.